# <i> tag icons are not displaying in my Ionic page

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, svg, icons

I am trying to use  tag icon in the html but it's not showing the icon.

This is how I am trying to display the icon but it's not displaying the icon

```
<i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
```

But whereas if I use icon like below it's displaying the icon

```
<fa-icon [icon]="['fas','plus']"></fa-icon>
```

But I need to display Icon as in the below type in order to do my logics.

```
<i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
```

Any Help, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the font awesome library is properly loaded on the page. If you are using the Angular CLI, you can add the following line to the  section of your HTML file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Once the library is loaded and available, you can use the  tag to display the icon.

Comment: whereas this icon is getting displayed in another page though but not getting displayed in my newly generated component

Answer (score 0):

You must be missing an link tag in the header of the index.html. Also try to use:

```
<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
```

When I'v tried to use the i tag for icons, i noticed the "fas" was not working for me. I had to remove the "s"

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<fa-icon [icon]="faPlus"></fa-icon>
```